# How copy bufferedreader into bufferedwriter for pdf files in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, buffer

How can I copy `BufferedReader` into `BufferedWriter` for pdf files in android?

The problem is I want to copy a file with gms library (I can't download with gms, just copy) so if I read every row with `BufferedReader` how can I copy with `BufferedWriter` and save pdf files? Every idea is appreciated Thank's

Comment: I need to copy pdf files(binary files) read and write...but i don't know how

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `Readers` and `Writers` are for character data. PDF files are binary. You should be using `InputStreams` and `OutputStreams.`

Comment: Yes, you alternately call `read()`and `write()` in a loop until you encounter end of stream. The code required is trivial and has been posted here hundreds of times. By me.

Comment: What if some chars are not being written correctly, how to check the charset?